# How to remove lines from textarea 1 which not contains each lines in textarea 2 ? [PHP]

Tags: php, textarea

Example

Textarea 1:

```
A123
B456
C789
D012
```

Textarea 2:

```
123
789
```

And when click button will show this result:

```
A123
C789
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are having troble in some part of the code, please post your full code, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below,

```
$data = ["A123","B456"];
$data1 = ["123"];
$newArr = array();
foreach($data1 as $val) {
    foreach($data as $fVal) {
        if(stristr($fVal,$val)) {
            $newArr[] = $fVal;
        }
    }
}

print "<pre>"; print_r($newArr);
```